# Why DevTools debugger detaches from App on Android Emulator?

Tags: android, cordova, debugging, android-emulator, google-chrome-devtools

My workflow is very simple, works for hello world app and worked for my app for some time (but not now).

1. Launch AVD (any of several I have configured)
2. `cordova run --target=emulator-5554 android`
3. Go to `chrome://inspect/#devices` tab in Chrome https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkyWC.jpg
4. Inspect my app running happily on emulator.

Inspection runs for a few seconds and then shows this:
http://imgur.com/fnd5MpF (sorry, don't have reputation enough to post images directly)

If I connect to emulator with ADB `adb -s emulator-5554 logcat` I see this error line:

`E/chromium( 3863): [ERROR:http_connection.cc(35)] Too large read data is pending: capacity=1048576, max_buffer_size=1048576, read=1048576`

Stuck with this problem and can't find anything in Google except for http_connection.cc code (which is pretty obvious but doesn't help anyway  in solving this issue)

Here's my adb log near error:

```
I/art     ( 1412): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4681(829KB) AllocSpace objects, 48(768KB) LOS objects, 19% free, 6MB/8MB, paused 20ms total 20ms
E/eglCodecCommon( 3863): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 3863): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/chromium( 3863): [ERROR:http_connection.cc(35)] Too large read data is pending: capacity=1048576, max_buffer_size=1048576, read=1048576
E/eglCodecCommon( 3863): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
```

Here's my cordova build log:

```
/usr/local/bin/cordova run --target=emulator-5554 android
Running command: /Users/imac/Documents/Prog/MyApp/platforms/android/cordova/run --target=emulator-5554
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.0.1/
JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Running: /Users/imac/Documents/Prog/MyApp/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/imac/Documents/Prog/MyApp/platforms/android/build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch=x86 -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
:preBuild
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:preReleaseBuild
:CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild
:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:validateDebugSigning
:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:zipalignDebug UP-TO-DATE
:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:cdvBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 5.246 secs
Built the following apk(s):
    /Users/imac/Documents/Prog/MyApp/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
Installing app on emulator...
Using apk: /Users/imac/Documents/Prog/MyApp/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've switched back to 21 API and previous build tools and now everything seems to work fine.

**UPDATE**
Cordova update also worked for me later on same issue.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182123